# Element is not shifting up

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I had put a text beside image. I want to shift that text up but not able to do it. Padding bottom is not working on it. Tried everything but still facing this issue.

Code:

```css
section {
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
}

section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.left-section {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

.right-section {
  float: right;
  width: 58%;
  margin-top: -70px;
  text-align: right;
  height: auto;
}

.pp {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3b6cff;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

figure img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: -22px;
}

.sp1 {
  /* margin-left: 323px;*/
  padding-right: 100%;
}

.pp1 {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-right: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul class="left-section">
    <li><img class="prog" src="images/programming.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="pp">DGcom</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="right-section">
    <li class="sp1">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/clk.png" alt="">
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="pp1">Opening Hour</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Pls Refer above code and let me know how to fixed it.

I'm creating section with logo and some details like opening hours, call us, etc. You can see the screenshot.

Comment: Please post a [repro] while paying extra attention to the word **minimal**! Note that images are inline elements (treated as inline-block by most browsers). padding influence all elements not just text! However, in your case, you should look into Flexbox! Aligning elements should be done with flexbox and never with `float`! `float` is a property to float an element within a flow text not to align items next to each other. That is an outdated technique from before 2012 when you neither had Flexbox nor CSS Grid.

Comment: The `padding-right: 100%` you set on `.sp1` forces the following `<li>`("Opening hour") into the next line (below the circle). It seems you have not yet fully understood, what padding is or how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply use grid to align items as like as you want

look likes this:

```css
h4 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
}
section ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left-section {
  width: 40%;
}
.right-section {
  width: fit-content;
  height: min-content;
}
.open {
  display: grid;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.pp {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3b6cff;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div img {
  width: 22px;
  height: auto;
}

.pp1 {
  color: #787878;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  height: fit-content;
  grid-column: 2;
}
.pp2 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  height: fit-content;
  grid-column: 2;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <ul class="left-section">
        <li><img class="prog" src="images/programming.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li class="pp">DGcom</li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="right-section">
        <li class="open">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="images/clk.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <h4 class="pp1">Opening Hour</h4>
          <h4 class="pp2">Mon-Fri,8:00-9:00</h4>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. I created 3 icons like in the above screenshot you can see. I wanted some space among them so I had given. But when I'm zooming in out it changing its position. I want then to have fixed position.

Comment: You can add flex-wrap: nowrap to main section to prevent go items in next line

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would advise changing your HTML. You are using two separate list items to create the icon-text element which doesn't really make sense. Based on the design, the icon is merely a visual indicator of what the text is telling the user. As such they should be part of the same element i.e. a single `<li>` containing both the icon and the text. Your html should therefore look more like this:

```
<ul class="right-section">
    <li class="sp1">
        <img class="prog" src="images/programming.png" alt="">
        <span class="pp1">Opening Hour</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To get the icon and the text to line up as you wish, `display: flex` is the solution I – and many others – would suggest. The CSS to achieve this, based on the HTML I've provided above would be as follows:

```
.prog {
    display: block;
}

.right-section {     
    list-style: none;
}

.sp1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

Setting the image to `display: block` will make it easier and more predictable to work with. As an aside, personally I would advise setting all `<img>`s to `display: block` in your reset.

Setting your `<li>` to `display: flex` will automatically put the icon and the text side by side. Setting `align-items: center` will then align the icon and the text as you want it to. I have used `gap` to create the space between the icon and the text but using `margin` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change HTML for your solution. Kindly check my answer.

```css
section {
        margin-top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        height: auto;
    }

    section ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .left-section {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
    }

    .right-section {
        float: right;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .pp {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #3b6cff;
        font-size: 38px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 11px;
    }

    figure {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    figure img {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 22px;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: -22px;
    }

    .pp1 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
       
    }

    .pp1 span {
        display: block;
    }

    / new /
    .ab {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: inherit;
    }
```

```html
    <section>
        <div class="ab">
        <ul class="left-section">
            <li><img class="prog" src="images/programming.png" alt=""></li>
            <li class="pp">DGcom</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="right-section">
            <li class="sp1">
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/clk.png" alt="">
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="pp1"><span>Opening Hour</span><span><b>Mon-Fri, 8:00-9:00</b></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
```